# How to delete/clear shared-preferences using key in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I am using the following code which clears all the shared-preferences but I just want to clear/delete particular shared-preferences value using key in a flutter.

For now, I have this which is clearing all the shared-preferences.

```
 SharedPreferences prefrences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefrences.clear();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
prefrences.remove("keyName")
```

Dart code is pretty easy to read so sometimes when there isn't sufficient documentation, you may just dive into code: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/481e8c251667bcb28d177bfc7d295d584e703bae/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences/lib/shared_preferences.dart#L146

Comment: This removes the keys from preference but not the value assigned to that key. How can we accomplish this (without setting an empty string to it)?

Answer (score 3):

You can delete a particular key if you know in advance which key you want to delete

```dart
SharedPreferences sharedPreference = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> keys = sharedPreference.getKeys();
    keys.remove("username");
```

Hopes that helps

Comment: does this remove the key or the string that belongs to the key too?

Comment: `.getKeys(`) is a `Set<String>` I believe, but either way, this code will only remove `"username"` from the **copy** of the keys stored in `keys`.

The keys actually in `SharedPreferences` will remain unaltered since Dart is pass by value.

Using `sharedPreferences.remove("username");` directly (like the other answer from @Manish) is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefrences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefrences.remove("keyName");
```